# Import changes from a defconfig into current .config

Tags: linux, makefile, config

As an example, let's say we start by doing

```
make xxx_defconfig
```

Then we activate low-level debug in the current config.

One day, the `xxx_defconfig` is changed.

How can we import the changes introduced by this new defconfig into our current `.config` while **keeping** the low-level debug options?

---

Obviously the low-level debug options is just an example. It could by any other options which is not conflicting with the changes introduced by the new defconfig.

Comment: What do the config files look like? How would merging them work? What do you do when a default and modified value differ?

Comment: If option didn't changed in current config : update it.
If option changed in current config : keep it.

Comment: How are you going to tell that? The original default config doesn't exist anywhere anymore. What does the config file look like? Is there something built-in that can parse it?

Comment: Make sense. Then let's say that it would ask for every conflict it encounter?

Comment: *What does the config look like?* How do you parse it? Are you looking for some existing tool or for ideas about how to write your own?

Comment: I was wondering if a tool already exists for that? Like a makefile phony target, or so. I may have not precise it but it's in the context of the configuration of a Linux kernel. Therefore, the config would look like anything valid in that context.

Comment: So you are asking if there is already a *linux kernel makefile* target that does what you want here?

Comment: yes for example, or any other tool?